# MultiScaleImage (DeepZoom) control on Windows Phone 7 and image collections

Tags: windows-phone-7, deepzoom, multiscaleimage

I am developing a WP7 application that displays and arranges images using a MultiScaleImage control.

Currently, I don't think my 'output' xml/dzc is properly formated to point to all of the sub images in the right places.

How do I export my Deep Zoom Composer project as a collection of images and access single subimages in my application? *(and yes, the data is online instead of local to the device)*

Sources:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/06/23/working-with-collections-in-deep-zoom.aspx
- http://blog.kirupa.com/?p=212
- http://blog.kirupa.com/?p=404
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645022(v=VS.95).aspx

Any and all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: EDIT: I did find one error. There's some restriction on picture naming when using Microsoft's deep zoom composer. I changed all of the pictures to pic_[number] and it output the files properly. The MSI control still doesn't load the image properly, but it is a step in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

This project might help you - http://deepzoomcontainer.codeplex.com - it includes a WP7 control

Comment: thanks, but that project doesn't use collections of images. It uses a single image.